# How can i export AzureRmAutomationCertificate?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

The certificate has exportable property set as "True". I need to use this certificate in different Azure subscription.

Comment: This PS Gallery script will export the automation certificate and store on an Azure Blob. It can then be used on Hybrid Worker servers. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Export-AzureAutomationRunasCertificate/1.0/DisplayScript

Answer (score 3):

Setting the certificate's exportable property to `True` in Azure Automation just means that the certificate will get marked as exportable in the certificate store of the sandbox where your Automation jobs run. It does not mean you can export the certificate through the Azure Automation control plane.

You need to either find the original certificate file that you uploaded to Azure Automation and use that, or from an Azure Automation runbook job write the certificate to a file in the same way you would any exportable certificate, and then save that file somewhere outside of the Automation sandbox (for example, uploading the file to Azure Blob Storage).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Happy to help. If this is the answer, please mark it as such